# Cakephp Error: The Images association is not defined on Projects

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I've got an CakePHP application with a "ProjectsManager" plugin.

**src/Model/Table/ImagesTable.php**:

```
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    ...
    $this->belongsToMany('ProjectsManager.Projects', [
        'className' => 'ProjectsManager.Projects',
        'foreignKey' => 'image_id',
        'targetForeignKey' => 'project_id',
        'joinTable' => 'images_projects'
    ]);
```

**plugins/ProjectsManager/src/Model/ProjectsTable.php**:

```
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    ...
    $this->hasMany('Images', [
        'className' => 'Images',
        'foreignKey' => 'project_id',
        'targetForeignKey' => 'image_id',
        'joinTable' => 'images_projects'
    ]);
    $this->hasOne('CoverImage', [
        'className' => 'Images',
        'bindingKey' => 'cover',
        'foreignKey' => 'id'
    ]);
```

**plugins/ProjectsManager/src/Controller/Publica/ProjectsController.php**:

```
    $this->paginate = [
        'fields' => ['Projects.title', 'Projects.slug', 'Projects.cover'],
        'conditions' => $where,
        'contain' => ['Images','CoverImage' => ['fields' => ['filename']]],
        'limit' => 15,
        'order' => ['id' => 'desc']
   ];
```

So, in my controller, I want to load all Projects and the associated Images, look at the code above. Running this gives me an error:

> The Images association is not defined on Projects.

So I've been searching and reading and found that I need to prefix the plugin to make it work. So I did as can be seen in the code. However the error remains.

Any ideas?

Comment: You have to add Plugin prefix in your has many association to call plugin's model table file. Please refer to this link for more details https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/plugins.html#plugin-models.

Comment: @Ishanvyas22, I did that, in ImageTable.php. If I should add it to in the ProjectsTable, how do I refer to the "main" app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some trying I found the solution.

In the App controllers (for example ImagesController.php) it works when you use `$this->Images->...`. With that code, the ImagesModel will be called.

Inside the plugin, this doesn't work... or at least, the ProjectsModel wasn't called.

So I needed to load the model manually by adding the following code to **ProjectsController.php**:

```
public function initialize()
{
    parent::initialize();
    $this->loadModel('ProjectsManager.Projects');
}
```